# Creating a label with text by clicking a button vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms

I would just like to ask a question how do I create or generate a label once I clicked a button. For example I typed something on a textbox on form1 for example "hello" then it will create a label on form2 with the text that i type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do, if you are wanting to create a label and add it to your 2nd form or add your text to an existing label on your second form.  This sample code will do the first option

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim frm2 As Form2 = New Form2    'Create your Form
    Dim lbl As Label = New Label     'Create your Label
    lbl.Location = New Point(50, 50) 'Set Label Location
    lbl.Text = TextBox1.Text         'Set Label Text
    lbl.ForeColor = Color.Red        'Set Label ForeColor
    frm2.Controls.Add(lbl)           'Add Label to it
    frm2.Show(Me)                    'Show Second Form

End Sub
```

Comment: I am wanting to create a label when I click the button and add it to my 2nd form with the text that I typed in my first form...I want to create this kind of loop when clicking button1..thanks sir!

Comment: Hi sir I want to create a label on my 2nd form once I click the button on my first form and the text on the textbox1 on my 1st form must be on the label of 2nd form too and should create a loop.. :) thanks for your answer sir i will definitely try this

Comment: problem solved thanks a lot sir more power to you :)

Answer (score 2):

try this code for create label

this a global variable in module

```
public lbl as new label
```

this code write into button click;

```
lbl.text=textbox1.text
```

this code add into thr frm2 the load event..

```
me.controls.add(lbl)
```

Comment: hi @pankeel where will i put this on form1 or on form2? thanks!

Comment: you can put in button click event

Comment: hi @pankeel what is the use of lbl.text = "hi" because I mean if i put a text on a textbox from form1 it will generate what I typed on the textbox in form1 to form2 to a label..

Comment: ah okay..sir the .control option has an error it says 'control' is not a member of windowsapplication1

Comment: sry,controls not control

Comment: ah okay sir...another error when I run the program it says Top-level control cannot be added to a control.

Comment: there are no errors anymore but nothing happens when i click the button1 the text on textbox1 is not transferring to form2's label and the form2 is not making a label either

Comment: Hi pankeel thanks for your help..i edited my question because my question awhile ago is not clear maybe you can help me now solve this problem...thanks again man

Comment: thanks also to you sir I really appreciate your help :) it helped me a lot too more power to you :)